# Borrar un nodo especifico de una lista simple en C

Tags: c, lista

tengo este código en el cual puedo agregar y recorrer una lista simple, mi problema es que al momento de usar la opción para eliminar un nodo en especifico, buscando un dato de este, solo me elimina el primer elemento, en este caso, el nombre, estoy seguro que hay algo mal en mi función eliminar_lista pero no se en qué, me podrían ayudar?

esta es mi funcion eliminar y visualizar:

```
void eliminar_lista(){

      struct agenda *aux; /* lo usamos para recorrer la lista */
      struct agenda *borrador;
      int i;
      int folio;
      i=0;
      aux = primero;
      printf("\nIntroduce el folio\n");
      scanf("%d",&folio);

      while (aux!=NULL) {
          if (folio==aux->folio){

            borrador=aux;
            aux=aux->siguiente;
            free(borrador);

          }
          else
          {
            aux = aux->siguiente;
            i++;

          }

      }
}
 void mostrar_lista() {
      struct agenda *auxiliar; /* lo usamos para recorrer la lista */
      int i;

      i=0;
      auxiliar = primero;
      printf("\nMostrando la lista completa:\n");
      while (auxiliar!=NULL) {
            printf( "Nombre: %s, Telefono: %s\n",
                    auxiliar->nombre,auxiliar->telefono);
            auxiliar = auxiliar->siguiente;
            i++;
      }
      if (i==0) printf( "\nLa lista está vacía!!\n" );
 }
```

Comment: Cuando encuentras el elemento que tiene el folio, apuntas `borrador` a ese elemento, y haces que `aux` apunte al siguiente y borras `borrador`, perdiendo el enlace con los elementos anteriores. Imagina que tienes que borrar el 2 de tres, haces que `aux` apunte al tercero y borras el segundo, ¿y el primero? Ya no apunta al tercero. Antes de borrar tienes que tener una referencia al elemento anterior al que vas a borrar y hacer que apunte el siguiente al que vas a borrar y entonces podrás borrar el del medio.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas del código que no entiendo. 
La variable "primero" en la función "eliminar_lista" no está declarada. Como obtiene la función la dirección de memoria del primer elemento de la lista?
Que función cumple el contador "i" ? Pareciera que ninguna.

Luego, si lo que pretendes hacer es eliminar un nodo particular y no la lista entera, la función debería llamarse eliminar_nodo en lugar de eliminar_lista.

Para hacer ello debes tener en consideración tres casos:
1) Que sucede si el primer nodo de la lista es el que buscas?
2) Que sucede si no es el primer nodo, y es un nodo intermedio?
3) Que sucede si es el último nodo de la lista?

Te dejo este código comentado para que lo puedas analizar:

```
agenda * eliminar_nodo(agenda * lista, int folio)
{
    agenda * seg;
    agenda * ante;  //apunta al nodo anterior que seg.

    if((lista != NULL) && folio != lista->folio ))
    {
        agenda * aux = lista;
        lista = lista->siguiente; //salteo el primer nodo.
        free(aux); //elimino el primer nodo.
    }
    else
    {
        seg = lista;
        while((seg != NULL) && folio != lista->folio ))
        {
            ante = seg; //adelanto una posicion la var ante.
            seg = seg->siguiente; //avanzo al siguiente nodo.
        }
        //en este punto tengo en la variable ante la direccion de memoria del
        //nodo anterior al buscado, y en la variable seg, la dir de memoria del
        //nodo que quiero borrar.
        if( seg!= NULL)
        {
            ante->siguiente = seg->siguiente; //salteo el nodo que quiero eliminar.
            free(seg); //elimino el nodo.
        }
    }
    return lista; //debo retornar el puntero al primer nodo, por el tipo de pasaje de parametros.
    //No puedo modificar el contenido de la var lista, que no es lo mismo
    //que modificar *lista (contenido de la direccion de memoria apuntada
    //por lista.
    //Otra forma de resolverlo es poner el par metro **lista. :)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste bastante, en mi caso "primero" es un apuntador dirigido al primero nodo de la lista, tu codigo me ayudo bastante, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, mi programa solo elimina el primer dato de la estructura agenda, me mantiene el segundo y el tercero, te paso mi codigo completo por si gustas ayudarme: https : // onlinegdb.com / HJRlQnIrI

Comment: Funciona todo a excepción de las funciones "eliminar_lista(la que hace el intento de eliminar nodo)" y "eliminar_nodo"

Comment: Fernando, no tengo una PC cerca ahora, pero ese codigo funciona? Creo que el error esta en como agregas nodos nuevos a la lista. Si la lista es nula, primero=nuevo, eso esta ok. Si no es nula, haces aux=primero y luego while(aux!=null) { ante=aux; aux=aux->siguiente; } y luego ante->siguiente=nuevo;. La referencia al ultimo no es necesaria para las listas simples.

Comment: Aqui tienes ejemplos de varias funciones con listas. No usa variables globales sino que pasa por referencia la lista y la devuelve como valor se retorno. Espero te sirva. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqcxse24bg1q96s/listas.c?dl=0

Comment: Vale, te agradezco mucho tu ayuda!